# Postfix unknown user

Tags: postfix

My system use Postfix, dovecot, OpenDS (LDAP), PAM, amavisd-new, spamassasin, clamav, procmail

User was authenticated via the OpenDS, Recently I recieve too many Spam message that send to the unknow user form my domain for example unknow@mydomain.com, is there a way to auto reject the messages from unknown user which is not in the OpenDS

Thanks Folks,

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how you have configured postfix you can check if the address exists before accepting the message.

- For local users you can just integrate your LDAP using PAM
- For virtual users postfix provides LDAP lookups too.

http://www.postfix.org/LDAP_README.html